# How to reset all NTFS partitions back to default(Read/Write) state?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, gparted, reset, read-only

I can't copy any file or folder to my NTFS partitions, but i can copy from them to my home. I think that all of them has been changed to read only state after i make changes in some partitions using Gparted. so what to do to reset them to read/write state again ???

Answer (score 0):

Use "mount" command to see if it's mounted as read-only(ro).

If yes, just umount it and mount the NTFS partition with appropriate options:
mount /dev/sdxx -t ntfs-3g -o users,rw,uid=yourname,dmask=022 /mountpoint

If it has already mount with rw, remember to change permission of the mount point at the first time.
chown yourname /mountpoint

Comment: here is the command before mounting any NTFS partition: http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/1293/mountg.png

Comment: And here is the command after mounting some NTFS partitions: http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/2574/mount2b.png

Comment: so what to do now ???